# Find a vector $Z$ such as $\Sigma-ZZ^\top>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have this problem:

Find a vector $Z$ such as $\Sigma-ZZ^\top$ is positive definite. Here $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

In some papers I see that they take $Z_j=\rho\sqrt{\Sigma_{jj}}$ where $\rho\in (0,1)$, but I think that this is not true always..

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\Sigma$, do you mean the covariance matrix of $Z$ in particular?

Comment: No, $\Sigma$ is a given covariance matrix. I want to find a vector $Z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such as $\Sigma-ZZ^\top>0$

Comment: Of course $Z\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the unique positive definite square root of $\Sigma$. By matrix congruence, $\Sigma-ZZ^T$ is positive definite if and only if $I-(P^{-1}Z)(P^{-1}Z)^T$ is positive definite, i.e. it's positive definite if and only $\|P^{-1}Z\|<1$.

So, any $Z$ whose norm is sufficiently small will do. In particular, any $Z$ with $\|Z\|<\min_i \lambda_i(P) = \sqrt{\min_i\lambda_i(\Sigma)}$ will do. If $u$ is a unit eigenvector of $\Sigma$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Z=\rho u$ with any $\rho\in(0,\sqrt{\lambda})$ will also do the trick.

In contrast, if you take $Z=\rho\sqrt{\Sigma_{jj}}$ with $\rho\in(0,1)$, the resulting matrix is not always positive definite. E.g. if we take $\rho=0.5$, then
$$
\pmatrix{1&-0.6\\ -0.6&1}
-\pmatrix{0.5\\ 0.5}\pmatrix{0.5&0.5}
=\pmatrix{0.75&-0.85\\ -0.85&0.75}
$$
is indefinite.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how congruence work. Can you explain that a little more or give me some good literature about matrix, semidefinite matriz, etc.